# Ambient context scope WCF instance provider

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm intend to use the ambient context scope in my project, which is described at this [location](https://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/).
I's a client/server application, the clients are connected by WCF services.
The question is now how to implement an WCF instance provider. 
The approach that I tried always gets an error message "System.InvalidOperationException: DbContextScope instances must be disposed of in the order in which they were created!" when the context should be disposed.

Has anybody a solution to manage that?

Code snipped of my instance provider:

```
public class MyInstanceProvider<T> : IInstanceProvider, IContractBehavior where T : class
{
    DbContextScopeFactory _dbContextScopeFactory;
    Dictionary<int, IDbContextScope> _Contexts = new Dictionary<int, IDbContextScope>();

    public MyInstanceProvider( DbContextScopeFactory dbContextScopeFactory )
    {
        _dbContextScopeFactory = dbContextScopeFactory;
    }

    public object GetInstance( InstanceContext instanceContext )
    {
        IDbContextScope contextScope = _dbContextScopeFactory.Create();
        _Contexts[instanceContext.GetHashCode()] = contextScope;
        var _Repository = new RepositoryFactory<T>().GetInstance();

        return _Repository;
    }

    public object GetInstance( InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message )
    {
        return GetInstance( instanceContext );
    }

    public void ReleaseInstance( InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance )
    {
        var hashCode = instanceContext.GetHashCode();
        if (_Contexts.ContainsKey( hashCode ))
        {
            var contextScope = _Contexts[hashCode];
            contextScope.Dispose();
            _Contexts.Clear();
        }
    }
```

...

Answer (score 1):

There are three potential issues in your code.

1. It is not good to use `instanceContext.GetHashCode()` as dictionary key - hash codes are not guaranteed to be unique. Just use `instanceContext` itself.
2. In the `ReleaseInstance` method you check if dictionary has proper key, dispose the `contextScope` and then clean the whole dictionary (`_Contexts.Clear()`). I think you should replace `_Contexts.Clear()` with `_Contexts.Remove`.
3. You use usual `Dictionary` while your code may be executed in multiple threads by WCF. Better use `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: 1. Try to use GetHashCode() to get a unique key to reference the context scope object. Made some test and it seems to be unique. My first try was to store the context scope object itself with same result.
2+3. You are right, but that's not the issue.

Comment: Then it is details of `DbContextScope` that hit you. Message says that you cannot create scope1 and scope2 and then dispose them in the same order: scope1 and scope2. Are you using any well-known DbContextScope or is it something custom?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
Hoped to find anybody that is familiar with "Mehdi Ambient ContextScope" that can give me a hint.

Comment: Ambient scope just means that it puts itself into the current `CallContext`. And exception mean that you effectively has nested contexts, i.e. the code creates new DbScopeContext when one was already created in the current `CallContext`. How is your WCF service designed (callbacks, calling into itself, etc?) which may lead  to call into same service?